# Django - Find missing invitations for an event

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I need to pick the community's brain on django. I'm still learning and the layer abstraction is my major challenge (as compared to a PHP/SQL script)

Here's an extract of my models:

A very simple contact, but with a "level" (like basic, gold, ...)

```
class customer(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, editable = False)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, editable = False)

    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    fk_level = models.ForeignKey(level, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
[...]
```

An event with customers (any number) that need to be invited to:

```
class event(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, editable = False)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, editable = False)

    eventdate =  models.DateField('Date de la soirée')
    fk_customer = models.ManyToManyField(customer, blank=True)
[...]
```

The invites to an event, for a customer.

```
class invite(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, editable = False)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, editable = False)

    fk_customer = models.ForeignKey(customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fk_event = models.ForeignKey(event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
[...]
```

The description of the level, with the number of invites to be sent based on the customer's level.

```
class level(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, editable = False)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, editable = False)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    eventinvites = models.IntegerField(default=2)
[...]
```

I don't want (and probably don't know how) to create the invites as soon as I add a customer to an event. Because I would need to manage removing a customer, and also manage a deletion of an invite.

So what I need is, for each event, to check if we have enough invites based on the customer level.

If there are no "invite" to an event for a "basic" customer, I would need to list "eventinvites" (2) invites (I can manage the creation once I know how many).
If there is only 1 invite, then I would only need to list 1. And if there are more than 1, then I don't have to do anything.

In stantard python code, I would probably walk the events, then for each of them, and for each of the customers that have been invited, walk the invites and check if how many I have that match the customer and event. If less than "eventinvites", I would add the event / customer pair to a list of "to do".

Something like

```
1   missing_invites = []
2   for event in Events:
3      for invited_customer in (Customers where event.fk_customer):
4           invite_count = 0
5           for invites in (Invites where invite.fk_customer==invited_customer and
6                           invite.fk_event == event.id):
7               invite_count += 1
8           if invite_count < event.fk_customer.fk_level.eventinvites:
9               missing_invites += (event, invited_customer)
```

In Django, I can create the view with Events, Invites and Customers in the context.
I can walk the Events (line 2), then filter on the Customers (line 3), and list the invites that have already been created.

views.py:

```
class MissingInvitesView(PermissionRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = invite
    template_name = 'missing.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["Cards"] = event.objects.all() #because it's easier 
                                               to understand
        context["Events"] = event.objects.all()
        context["Customers"] = customer.objects.all()
```

And missing.html:

```
    {% for event in Events %}
        {% for customer in event.fk_customer.all %}
            {% with eventInvite=Invites|matchingEvent:event.id %}
                {% for customereventInvite in eventInvite|matchingCustomer:customer.id %}
                    <br>{{ customereventInvite }}
                {%endfor%}
            {%endwith%}
        {% endfor%}
    {%endfor%}
```

With this, I can get the list of invites that exist. But I can't figure out a way to either count these and display something if one is missing.

I'm still working with generic (class) views, because it's easier. Should I start learning about standard (def) views ? Would it work ?

Thanks a lot for your help.
Jm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out how to complete my challenge.

Missing.html has been updated to :

```
{% for event in Events %}
    {% for customer in event.fk_customer.all %}
        {% with eventInvites=Invites|matchingEvent:event.id %}
            {% for newInvite in eventInvites|MissingInvitesFor:customer.id %}
                        <br>New Invite required
            {%endfor%}
        {%endwith%}
    {% endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

and my custom_tags:

```
@register.filter(name="matchingEvent")
def matchingEvent(invites, event_id):
    return invites.filter(fk_event=event_id).all()


@register.filter(name="MissingInvitesFor")
def MissingInvitesFor(invites, current_customer_id):
    current_customer = customer.objects.filter(id = current_customer_id).first()
    customer_level = current_customer.fk_userlevel
    required_invites = int(customer_level.eventinvites)
    existing_invites = invites.filter(fk_customer=current_customer_id).count() 
    return range(required_invites - existing_invites)
```

It might not be the most efficient or the cleanest (because I create new queries in custom_tags), but it works.

Any comments welcome.